# How to export mysql database in Workbench from repostory

Tags: mysql, github, mysql-workbench

I got a project cloned from github. I need to export database that is placed in the repo. But I do not any ideas how to get it.
I installed Workbench, made MySQL Connection with username, login, hostname: localhost, port 3306. But I have no idea what to do next. I am a newbie in SQL.

Comment: "Database placed in the repo" ??  Please [edit] your question to tell us what form your database takes in the repo.  Is it a `.sql` file? Or what?

Answer (score 1):

I think you cloned some .sql and what to know how to insert this in your mySQL server right? If i understand it right you should try this step.

1. Create MySQL Server so if you don't have some you can download community version
   https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ that's free
2. Ppen MySQL Workbench
3. Connect your MySQL server with MySQL workbench
4. In file menu click that and choose "Run SQL Script" and open file that you cloned
5. run
6. SQL Script will make your database